# Вывести нужное количество картинок из массива?

Tags: php

При выборе определенных заказов формируется массив с данными.
Мне нужно вывести определенное количество одинаковых картинок. Например выбрал два заказа в этом заказе есть товар и в одном и во втором (может сколько угодно),  заказ в ном 2 товара количество которых равно 10 и 5, мне нужно что бы количество товара соответствовало количество картинок, Например товаров 10 и 5 и вывелось стока же картинок.

controller

```
 $this->data['results'] = array();

    foreach ($barcode as $results){
       foreach ($results as $result){

           $this->data['count'][] = $result['quantity'];

           $this->data['results'][] = array(
            'barcode' => $result['barcode'],
            'quantity' => $result['quantity']
           );
       }
    }
```

views

```
<?php foreach($results as $result){ ?>

        <?php if(!empty($result['barcode'])){ ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $result['barcode'] ?>" style="width: 52.5mm; height: auto ">
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <?php echo 'No img'?>
        <?php } ?>
```

```
'quantity' => $result['quantity'] - это количество товара
$result['barcode'] - это картинка
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмите функцию [str_repeat()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-repeat.php). Первым параметром задайте

```
 '<img src="' . $result['barcode'] . '" style="width: 52.5mm; height: auto ">'
```

вторым

```
$result['quantity']
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло.